# Codeigniter Photo upload taking a lot of time

Tags: codeigniter

I use codeigniter framework for my new project and the photo upload is taking a lot of time in server. what could be the reason. The server is bluehost

Answer (score 0):

If it's only the upload and not any processing then any slowness would be due to your internet connection and the size of the file being uploaded.

Comment: dint get by wat u meant by processing.....i upload photos and photos and thumbnails are created for each foto....but photo upload is taking a lot of time

Comment: Processing is whatever you do with the image once it is uploaded. If it is the upload, it's probably your New Delhi connection that is slow.